# Complile A DLL From Github

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have found a great dev on github who has some great code i am using at the moment. I need to edit one of the files referenced in the DLL (that i referenced from nuget).

https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

luckily the dev has all the .cs files available on github to download. I have made the changes i need to his code but have no idea on how to compile them into a dll for use in my project.

What should i start researching - it is something i have never even remotely had to do before. If anyone has a link to a guide i could follow or a good starting point to learn from i would appreciate it.

thanks!

Comment: Is the project correctly seen as a class library?

Comment: The project has a `.sln` file.  Does opening that file not work?

Answer (score 2):

Start by downloading the project from GitHub. Then open the solution file in Visual Studio and make the necessary changes to the source code. Then compile. Finally reference the compiled assembly into your application (don't use the official NuGet).

Or if you want to use the NuGet you will have to build it by yourself with the changes you have made to the source code and then reference the new NuGet.

After you have completed those changes you might submit a Pull Request to the author on GitHub so that he can integrate your changes directly into his repository and make them available through his NuGet.